# Double Fusion Drive Volume in Startup Menu after DIY Drive Fusion

Tags: ssd, partition, fusion-drive

After replacing the SuperDrive in my MacBook Pro I copied the Recovery HD to a USB stick and booted from it. Then I ran `diskutil cs create MacintoshFusionDrive /dev/disk0 /dev/disk1` (SSD, HDD), reinstalled MacOS from the stick and migrated from my backup.

Unfortunately, I didn't think about keeping the Recovery HD, so I ran from the stick `diskutil cs resizeVolume` on the logical volume and `diskutil cs resizeDisk <UUID> <size> "Recovery HD" <size>` on the coreStorage disk of the HDD to make a new partition on wich I then copied the contents of my recovery stick.

Somehow the name of the recovery partition *only in the startup menu (alt boot)* was localized in German but I got rid of that by running `sudo bless --folder /Volumes/Recovery\ HD -label Recovery\ HD`. I don't really understand why this happened and how that exact line solved problem. But all seem's fine now. Perhaps I accidentally copied the image on the drive back to the drive directly. Anyhow.

It remains to resolve the last oddity that in the startup hdd menu, there are two `Fusion Drive`s wich *both* start up the system just fine. It's not a real problem but I would like to know what's causing this and how to get rid of the duplication.

```
$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 3D7E41ED-2D3B-4C46-A696-2C0C156B6BF6
    =========================================================
    Name:         MacintoshFusionDrive
    Status:       Online
    Size:         625672790016 B (625.7 GB)
    Free Space:   154107904 B (154.1 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume B7097B08-1AD3-4AAA-BD1B-88BF5E0EF57E
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     127691702272 B (127.7 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 12F98EE5-AE4C-4A14-8276-7915BCD06999
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     497981087744 B (498.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 5E001AF2-DE08-46C2-A1DA-5637AB534553
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume AC804BCD-419F-4AA0-AE01-1C7D25FF3949
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          619999997952 B (620.0 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Fusion Drive
            Volume Name:           Fusion Drive
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS


$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         127.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         498.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             1.1 GB     disk1s4
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Fusion Drive           *620.0 GB   disk2

$ sudo gpt -r show disk1
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  972619312      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  973028952    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  974298488    2212488      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  976510976     262159         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
$ diskutil info disk1
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      Hitachi HTS545050B9SA02 Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 SATA
   SMART Status:             Verified

   Total Size:               500.1 GB (500107862016 Bytes) (exactly 976773168 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                No

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 Yes
   Solid State:              No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

Please let me know, if anything else could be of help.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same question...
Fusion Drive utilizes a component of OS X called CoreStorage to work. When you boot your Mac holding down Option, you are booting into a screen running in the low-level EFI environment, before OS X has started. EFI doesn't understand what a home-built Fusion Drive is, but sees two physical drives capable of booting into OS X.

I'm not sure of the mechanics of why factory-built Fusion Drives in the latest Macs act differently but my guess is that there is a firmware chip of some sort, like you said. Apple is known to put custom firmware on some of their hard drives.
(Answer taken from another post)

Comment: Hi Roman, Welcome to Ask Different, Please share the link of the original post, and elaborate the answer a bit more, adding details.